# Question on parabolic smoothing of nonhomogeneous heat equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

> Suppose $\Omega $ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb R^n$ and let $u$ be
>   the weak solution of the initial value problem for the nonhomogeneous
>   heat equation: $\begin{cases} \partial_t u-\Delta u=f,\;\;\;t\in
>  (0,T)\\ u(x,0)=u_0\\ \end{cases}$
>
> **If $f\in L^1(\Omega \times (0,T))$ then what assumption should we have on $u_0$ in order to deduce a bound for the solution $u$ in the
>   parabolic Sobolev space?**

To be honest, I'm not even sure if we can obtain any bound for the given $f$ but since we have one for the Poisson equation [by Stampacchia](http://www.numdam.org/article/SJL_1963-1964___3_1_0.pdf)(Proposition 4.3), I 'm motivated to think that it should exist also one for the heat equation (most of the times, parabolic pdes have analog results to the elliptic ones).

However I wasn't able to find anything, so this is why I'm asking here.

Any help or hint will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most techniques are based on casting the equation to a funcional analysis settings involving inner products and dual spaces. You paper also requires $f \in L^2$, so it would be reasonable to assume the same. Otherwise, expressions like $<f,\phi>$, where <,> denotes the inner product, do not make sense. And any weak solutions are based on being multiplied by a test function $\phi$.  
Most bounds I know seem to involve a boundary condition term. Without one, it might be hard to bound all solutions uniformly.